# Excel VBA - Runtime Error 6 - Overflow. Only affecting one user

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, overflow

I have a forms driven spreadsheet which has been in use for many years.  It is constantly developed by me as business needs change.

One procedure which has not changed for a long time is to create an Outlook calendar appointment in our Installer's calendars which are shared with all users of the spreadsheet.  This procedure attaches the active workbook plus a number of mailmerge documents to the Outlook appointment then displays the appointment for the user to add any further information.

A couple of weeks ago this started failing.  Users kept getting a message saying that Excel was waiting for another action to complete and offering the choice to "switch to" which, if selected, took them to Outlook where it was not responding.  Eventually, 2/3 minutes, the appointment would get displayed and the code in the spreadsheet would complete correctly.  I was putting this down to a possible Windows or Office update.  After a bit of debugging I discovered that the line of code that attempts to attach the active workbook was where it was waiting.  So I put in a workaround where instead of attaching the active workbook, I save a copy of it first in a temporary folder, attach that to the Outlook appointment and then delete the temporary file.  This then put everything back, as far as the users were concerned, to the way it had been working with no delay.

However, one user has now got an Overflow error in that procedure.  But for everyone else it's working perfectly.

Here is the full code for the procedure.  Hopefully I have used the correct method to display it as a code block!

```
Public Sub Create_Calendar_Appointment()

    Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim outNameSpace As Namespace
    Dim outSharedName As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim outCalendarFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim outAppointment As AppointmentItem
    Dim SharedMailboxEmail As String
    Dim varFilePrefix As String
    Dim KeySafeInstall As Boolean
    Dim AppointmentDuration As Integer
    Dim strMsg As String
    Dim strbody As String
    Dim strSubject As String
    Dim strAppType As String
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim CalAttachFileName As String
    Dim CalAttachFilePath As String
    Dim CalAttachSAPath As String
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    
    On Error GoTo err_handler

    subORfunction_Name = "Create_Calendar_Appointment"
    error_Description = ""

    
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    
    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    
    CalAttachFileName = wb1.Name

    error_Description = "Error saving spreadsheet copy in c:\temp"

'   This is a workardound.  In January 2023, possibly after an Office or Windows update, all users were experiencing a problem with the creation and opening of the Outlook appointment.
'   This mainfested itself with an error saying that Excel was waiting for another OLE action to complete.  This was with an option of OK, Switch To or Cancel.  Selecting Switch To
'   took the user to Outlook which was not responding.  After a couple of minutes the Outlook Appointment would appear and the rest carried on as normal.
'   In the original version of this sub I was just attaching the active workbook to the Outlook appointment.  Commenting that out got rid of the long delay and the error messages.
'   This workaround was introduced where I now save a copy of the workbook in to a temp folder, attach that to the appointment and then delete it.
'   The workaround has worked for all users except for 1 who is now (Feb 2023) getting a Runtime Error 6, overflow when she enters this procedure.  Everyone else is working fine.
'   She has been given a new laptop in case it was linked to hardware or software but still the same.  Users are running a mixture of Windows 10 and 11.
    
    wb1.SaveCopyAs "C:\temp\" & CalAttachFileName
    
    error_Description = ""

    varFilePrefix = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CreateInstall.create_Authority, Range("installtype"), 3, False)
    KeySafeInstall = False
    AppointmentDuration = 60
    
    error_Description = "Cannot open shared mailbox for " & create_Installer
    
    SharedMailboxEmail = create_Installer
    
    error_Description = ""
       
    If Not IsOutlookRunning Then
        
    error_Description = "Problem getting Outlook to run (it wasn't already running)"
        
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "outlook.exe", 3, False
        Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Else
    
    error_Description = "Problem switching to Outlook"

        Set outApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    End If
    
    error_Description = "Problem setting object variables for Outlook Calendar"
    
    Set outNameSpace = outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set outSharedName = outNameSpace.CreateRecipient(SharedMailboxEmail)
    Set outCalendarFolder = outNameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(outSharedName, olFolderCalendar)
    
    error_Description = ""
    
'==== Set up the message content ================================================
               ' Set up the body message
               If Me.create_CautionReason = "" Then
                    strbody = "Referral Date - " & Me.create_ReferralDate & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                Else
                    strbody = "CAUTION - " & Me.create_CautionReason & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Referral Date - " & Me.create_ReferralDate & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                End If
                
                strbody = strbody & Me.create_Address & vbCrLf
                
                If Me.create_Address2 <> "" Then
                    strbody = strbody & Me.create_Address2 & vbCrLf
                End If
                
                If Me.create_Address3 <> "" Then
                    strbody = strbody & Me.create_Address3 & vbCrLf
                End If
                
                If Me.create_Address4 <> "" Then
                    strbody = strbody & Me.create_Address4 & vbCrLf
                End If
                
                strbody = strbody & Me.create_PostCode & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Landline - " & Replace(Me.create_Landline, " ", "") & vbCrLf & "Mobile - " & Replace(Me.create_Mobile, " ", "")
                
                If Me.create_Directions <> "" Then
                    strbody = strbody & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Me.create_Directions
                End If
                
                If Me.Create_Name_Booking <> "" Then
                    strbody = strbody & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Appointment booked by: " & Me.Create_Name_Booking & " - " & Me.Create_Number_Booking
                End If
                
                If Me.Create_Name_Attending <> "" Then
                    strbody = strbody & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Me.Create_Name_Attending & " will be attending the installation.  Contact number is " & Me.Create_Number_Attending
                End If
                
                If Me.Create_Known_Conditions <> "" Then
                    strbody = strbody & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Known Conditions: " & Me.Create_Known_Conditions
                End If
                
                
                strbody = strbody & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Me.create_Base_Alarm & " -  " & Me.create_BaseAlarm_Serial
                strbody = strbody & vbCrLf & Me.create_Pendant & " - " & Me.create_Pendant_Serial
                
                If Me.create_Add1 <> "" Then
                    strbody = strbody & vbCrLf & Me.create_Add1 & " - " & Me.create_Add1_Serial
                    If Left(Me.create_Add1, 3) = "Key" Then
                        AppointmentDuration = 90
                    End If
                End If
                
                If Me.create_Add2 <> "" Then
                    strbody = strbody & vbCrLf & Me.create_Add2 & " - " & Me.create_Add2_Serial
                    If Left(Me.create_Add2, 3) = "Key" Then
                        AppointmentDuration = 90
                    End If
                End If
                
                If Me.create_Add3 <> "" Then
                    strbody = strbody & vbCrLf & Me.create_Add3 & " - " & Me.create_Add3_Serial
                    If Left(Me.create_Add3, 3) = "Key" Then
                        AppointmentDuration = 90
                    End If
                End If
                
                If Me.create_Add4 <> "" Then
                    strbody = strbody & vbCrLf & Me.create_Add4 & " - " & Me.create_Add4_Serial
                    If Left(Me.create_Add4, 3) = "Key" Then
                        AppointmentDuration = 90
                    End If
                End If
                
                If Me.create_Add5 <> "" Then
                    strbody = strbody & vbCrLf & Me.create_Add5 & " - " & Me.create_Add5_Serial
                    If Left(Me.create_Add5, 3) = "Key" Then
                        AppointmentDuration = 90
                    End If
                End If
                
                If Me.create_Add6 <> "" Then
                    strbody = strbody & vbCrLf & Me.create_Add6 & " - " & Me.create_Add6_Serial
                    If Left(Me.create_Add6, 3) = "Key" Then
                        AppointmentDuration = 90
                    End If
                End If
                
                strbody = strbody & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                
                strbody = strbody & "SAVE THESE ATTACHMENTS TO C:\TEMP INSTALLS FOLDER AND OPEN SPREADSHEET FROM THERE" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                
                StringToConvert = ChangeToUpperCase(create_AppointmentType)
                
                If Me.create_chkBox_Caution = True Then
                    strSubject = Me.create_PostCode & " - *CAUTION*" & " - " & ConvertedString & " - " & Me.create_Title & " " & Me.create_Name & ". SA " & Me.create_SA_Num
                Else
                    strSubject = Me.create_PostCode & " - " & ConvertedString & " - " & Me.create_Title & " " & Me.create_Name & ". SA " & Me.create_SA_Num
                End If

'======== End of setting up message content ============================================

    error_Description = "Error is in generating the appointment and attaching the files"

    Set outAppointment = outCalendarFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
    With outAppointment
        .Subject = strSubject
        .Start = Me.create_InstallDate & " " & Me.create_InstallTime
        .Duration = AppointmentDuration
        .Importance = olImportanceNormal
        .ReminderSet = False
        .Location = Me.create_PostCode & ", " & Me.create_Address & ", " & Me.create_Address4 & ", " & Me.create_Landline
        .AllDayEvent = False
        .Body = strbody
        .Categories = Me.create_AppointmentCategory
        .Attachments.Add "C:\temp\" & CalAttachFileName
        .Attachments.Add TemplatePath & varFilePrefix & "-FeedingOn.docx"
        .Attachments.Add TemplatePath & varFilePrefix & "-Contract.doc"
        .Attachments.Add TemplatePath & "WTC-Contract With Response.doc"
        .Attachments.Add TemplatePath & "MergeData.xls"
        .Attachments.Add TemplatePath & "MindMeInfo.docx"
        .Attachments.Add TemplatePath & "Direct Debit Mandate Merge.doc"
        .Save
        .Display
    End With

    error_Description = "Error deleting temporary file in c:\temp"

    Kill "C:\temp\" & CalAttachFileName
    
    error_Description = ""
    
    Set outAppointment = Nothing
    Set outCalendarFolder = Nothing
    Set outNameSpace = Nothing
    Set outApp = Nothing

err_handler:
    Select Case Err_Occurred(subORfunction_Name, error_Description, Err.Number)
        Case Is = True: Resume 'try again
        Case Is = False: Resume Next 'cancel
    End Select
    
End Sub
```

For the user that's been having the problem we have replaced her laptop in case there was a hardware/software issue specific to her machine but it hasn't made any difference.

I've looked at the documentation about overflow which primarily points towards using wrong data types.  I can't see anything specifically in this procedure that fits that criteria.  And, of course, all other users (6 in total) are using this procedure every day, many times a day and all with no problem.

Would really appreciate it if someone was able to spot a problem in the code that I've missed.  I am not a developer!!  Would be very receptive to any suggestions for optimising the code.

Many thanks

David

Comment: Which line is causing the overflow error?

Comment: Is the one user that is having the problem using 32 bit office, while everyone else is using 64 bit?

Comment: Overflow is usually an Integer overflow, but your code doesn't show any numbers that could create such error. Maybe some other code is triggered? Comment out the `On Error`-statement, let the code run and tell is the line that is causing the error, else it will be impossible to help

Comment: @Rory it happens at the point where the outlook appointment is being created i.e.     With outAppointment

Comment: @Gravitate I haven't specifically checked, and I will, but as far as I'm aware we are all using 64bit.  IT build our laptops from a standard images so all versions should be the same.  But I will double-check.

Comment: That shouldn't be possible since that line doesn't actually *do* anything.

Comment: @FunThomas I've added the error handler code as an additional way of checking where the problem lies.  Previously I was just stepping through the code line by line.  Everything is fine until you get to the start of the With outAppointment block.

Comment: @Rory, yes a good point.  I will try and get hold of the user and I'll do another step through just to make 100% sure I've got the correct line.  But definitely everything works fine until you get to the With block.

Comment: so it errors on `With outAppointment`? Not one of the lines within the with block?

Comment: Just a guess: `Start` is a `Date`, but you are writing a string into it. That forces VBA to do a conversion, and maybe that conversion fails - likely because of different regional settings

Comment: @Gravitate - I've just had a session with my user and we stepped through the code and yes, I F8 to the line With outAppointment which highlights in yellow.  I then press F8 again and it immediately generates the overflow error.

Someone else has mentioned the .Date line where I'm storing a concatenated string so I'm going to comment out that line or change it to now()

Have also double-checked and we are all on the same 64 bit version of Excel.

Comment: @Rory please see my post above to gravitate.  Definitely the With outAppointment line.

Comment: @DavidJones Thats rather odd. Just for debug purposes, if you take out the with block completely, and just use `outAppointment.Subject = strSubject` and `outAppointment.Start = Me.create_InstallDate & " " & Me.create_InstallTime`, etc. Which line (if any) does it error on then?

Comment: Can you go to the VBA environment, Tools->Options, General, and activate "Break on all Errors" or at least "Break in Class Module". Are there any AddIns installed on that computer that could cause this error?

Comment: just a stupid question: what happens if some appointments are deleted beforehand
There are limits

Comment: @Gravitate thanks for the suggestion.  I've now been able to prove that it's actually this line which it's failing on:

    Set outAppointment = outCalendarFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)

I've had the complete WITH block removed completely with no replacement and also used the outAppointment.Subject = etc etc

Comment: @FunThomas I've checked and there are no add-ins active.